# How to suppress warning 'cannot resolve method' because you generate the method using annotation?

Tags: java, lombok

My goal is to learn on how to create annotation. So, I use the project lombok's `@Getter` annotation for practice. However, one thing bothers me is that the IntelliJ IDEA throws warning of `Cannot resolve method 'getId' in 'Product'`. Please note, compiling is not a problem.

What I did:

1. Enable annotation processing in the Settings.

My expected result: The IDE knows that `getId` method will be injected at compile-time.

My actual result: The IDE throws warning.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Main {
  public static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Product product = new Product();
    logger.debug(Integer.toString(product.getId()));
  }
}
```

```
import lombok.Getter;

public class Product {
  @Getter
  private int id = 10;
}
```

PS: I heard it needs Lombok plugin to be installed. Is there a way to do it without plugin? I need it to implement it in my own annotation.

Comment: Do you want to use "annotation processor"?

Comment: What you run into is exactly my main gripe about Lombok: it's not something that *can* be implemented in a pure annotation processor, so it depends on the plugin for your IDE and/or build system to work. It can't work without those plugins.

Comment: And a second pet peeve of mine: Annotations are **passive metadata**. They are in themselves nothing more than slightly more codified machine-readable comments. It's up to *some other piece of software* to interpret that metadata and make something happen based on them. Lombok is *one* approach of doing it and annotation processing is a similar one (less powerful than Lombok, but at least it's standardized and works everywhere). A third way to use them is something like Spring which reads and interprets annotations at runtime for its configuration.

Comment: @JoachimSauer that is exactly what I intend to do. To implement `@Autowired` and `@Service` kind of thing without the Spring Framework. I will take a look at annotation processing and Spring Depedency Injection tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lombok isn't an annotation processor. Lombok is a unique bit of software, and (as one of the core authors), what lombok does is not trivial in the slightest: You'd have to fork the lombok code base if you want to do lombok-esque things.

Looking at lombok as an example of what annotations can do is in that sense not a good idea: Lombok is its own thing, and merely uses annotations to know where to act, it is **not** a processor (but, weirdly enough, it registers itself as one in order to become part of the compilation process).

To answer your direct questions:

1. Yes, you need the lombok plugin installed; recent versions of intellij have it installed by default if memory serves.
2. No, lombok cannot be made to work without that.
3. However, an actual normal annotation processor would work just fine.
4. Basic (non-lombok) annotation processors **can only make new files** - they cannot change existing files. Only lombok can do that (and it requires a plugin). If you write a basic annotation processor (which therefore can only make new files), what you've done (turn on 'annotation processing') is all that is needed.

Note that basic annotation processors tend to need to go through a full build and have issues with incremental compilation (as in, incrementally compiling tools generally just compile everything, every time, if annotation processors are loaded. Most tools know lombok isn't an annotation processor / works just fine in incremental compilation scenarios and know not to fall back to 'compile all the things all the time'). For medium to large project, 'compile everything' is a gigantic time waster which you want to avoid.

Next steps for you:

- Consider if the changes you want to make can be done solely by making new files. If the answer is **No, I must change existing files**, give up. Or, fork lombok and spend half a year figuring out the inner workings of javac, ecj, and intellij :/
- If you CAN do the job by making only new files, know that the experience won't be as smooth and speedy as what lombok does. Forget lombok as an example, it's not a normal annotation processor. Find any tutorial on annotation processing / read up on the APIs / have a look at the source of a project such as [AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value) for an example of how a 'normal' annotation processor works. Know that you can do what you want, and all it takes is what you already did: Enable that 'run processors' checkbox.

Comment: Regarding the Lombok fork: I don't think you can implement the features Lombok provides with pure annotation processing, so this kind of work will always require explicit plugins (or the annotation processing possibilities be extended in a future Java version). AutoValue is a great example of a limited subset of what Lombok provides implemented using annotation processing.

Comment: @JoachimSauer .. and also a fine example of how it's quite a bit less productive, in that you're waiting around for a _lot_ more building. AutoValue (and any Annotation Processor) doesn't run until you save and the build goes through. lombok runs as you type.

Comment: @rzwitserloot my end goal is to create custom annotation like Spring Framework dependency injection e. g. `@Autowired` and `@Service`. I thought Lombok is simple (i was wrong), so I decided to check the Lombok annotation file for reference. Do you mean, Spring Framework suffers the incremental compile because it is pure annotation processing (without plugin)?

Comment: @kidfrom: Spring uses neither the Lombok approach nor annotation processing. It simply inspects classes at runtime using reflection and reads the annotations that way (see [`Class.getAnnotations()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getAnnotations()) and related methods.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the @rzwitserloot answer,
do not use Lombok as a means to learn annotations.

Instead,
read an annotation tutorial.
Here are some links:

- [Oracle's Annotation Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/)
- [Wikipedia's Annotation Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation)
- [Baeldung's Custom Annotation Article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-custom-annotation)